# Double free or corruption (out) on return

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm doing an assignment that involves calculating pi with threads. I've done this using mutex and it works fine, but I would like to get this version working as well. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct{
    int iterations;     //How many iterations this thread is going to do
    int offset;         //The offset multiplier for the calculations (Makes sure each thread calculates a different part of the formula)
}threadParameterList;

vector<double> partialSumList;

void* pi_calc(void* param){
    threadParameterList* _param = static_cast<threadParameterList*>(param);
    double k = 1.0;
    for(int i = _param->iterations * _param->offset + 1; i < _param->iterations * (_param->offset + 1); ++i){
        partialSumList[_param->offset] += (double)k*(4.0/((2.0*i)*(2.0*i+1.0)*(2.0*i+2.0))); 
        k *= -1.0;
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    //Error checking
    if(argc != 3){
        cout << "error: two parameters required [iterations][threadcount]" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if(atoi(argv[1]) <= 0 || atoi(argv[2]) <= 0){
        cout << "error: invalid parameter supplied - parameters must be > 0." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    partialSumList.resize(atoi(argv[2]));

    vector<pthread_t>           threadList    (atoi(argv[2]));
    vector<threadParameterList> parameterList (atoi(argv[2]));

    int iterations  = atoi(argv[1]),
        threadCount = atoi(argv[2]);

    //Calculate workload for each thread
    if(iterations % threadCount == 0){  //Threads divide evenly
        for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i){
            parameterList[i].iterations = iterations/threadCount;
            parameterList[i].offset = i;
            pthread_create(&threadList[i], NULL, pi_calc, &parameterList[i]);
        }
        void* status;
        for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i){
            pthread_join(threadList[i], &status);
        }

    }
    else{                               //Threads do not divide evenly
        for(int i = 0; i < threadCount - 1; ++i){
            parameterList[i].iterations = iterations/threadCount;
            parameterList[i].offset = i;
            pthread_create(&threadList[i], NULL, pi_calc, &parameterList[i]);
        }
        //Add the remainder to the last thread
        parameterList[threadCount].iterations = (iterations % threadCount) + (iterations / threadCount);
        parameterList[threadCount].offset = threadCount - 1;
        pthread_create(&threadList[threadCount], NULL, pi_calc, &parameterList[threadCount]);
        void* status;
        for(int i = 0; i < threadCount-1; ++i){
            pthread_join(threadList[i], &status);
            cout << status << endl;
        }
    }

    //calculate pi
    double pi = 3.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < partialSumList.size(); ++i){
        pi += partialSumList[i];
    }

    cout << "Value of pi: " << setw(15) << setprecision(15) << pi << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine in most cases. There are certain combinations of parameters that cause me to get a double free or corruption error on `return 0`. For example, if I use the parameters `100` and `10` the program creates 10 threads and does 10 iterations of the formula on each thread, works fine. If I use the parameters `10` and `4` the program creates 4 threads that do 2 iterations on 3 threads and 4 on the 4th thread, works fine. However, if I use `5` and `3`, the program will correctly calculate the value and even print it out, but I get the error immediately after. This also happens for `17` and `3`, and `10` and `3`. I tried `15` and `7`, but then I get a `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer` error when the threads are trying to be joined - although i think that's something for another question.

If I had to guess, it has something to do with `pthread_exit` deallocating memory and then the same memory trying to be deallocated again on `return`, since I'm passing the parameter struct as a pointer. I tried a few different things like creating a local copy and defining `parameterList` as a vector of pointers, but it didn't solve anything. I've also tried `erase`ing and `clear`ing the vector before `return` but that didn't help either.

Comment: `partialSumList.reserve(atoi(argv[2]));`  Is this what you really meant, or did you mean `resize`?

Comment: Turns out I actually should have used `resize`. I made the change but it didn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this issue:

You are writing beyond the vector's bounds:

```
    vector<threadParameterList> parameterList (atoi(argv[2]));
    //...
    int        threadCount = atoi(argv[2]);
    //...
    parameterList[threadCount].iterations = (iterations % threadCount) + (iterations / threadCount);
    parameterList[threadCount].offset = threadCount - 1;
```

Accessing `parameterList[threadCount]` is out of bounds.

I don't see in the code where `threadCount` is adjusted, so it remains the same value throughout that snippet.

Tip:  If the goal is to access the last item in a container, use `vector::back()`.  It works all the time for non-empty vectors.

```
    parameterList.back().iterations = (iterations % threadCount) + (iterations / threadCount);
    parameterList.back().offset = threadCount - 1;
```

Comment: I'm pretty upset I didn't catch that. I wonder why the program continued to execute correctly if I was stepping out of bounds, I thought the program would terminate whenever that happens. Even gdb told me the problem happened on `return` rather than an out of bounds error. Thank you!

Comment: The behavior is undefined when you access a vector element using `operator [ ]` and the index is out of bounds.  For bounds checking, use the `vector::at( )` function.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can see is you might be going past the end of the vector here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < partialSumList.capacity(); ++i)
```

[`capacity()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) returns how many elements the vector can hold.  This can be more than the [`size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) of the vector.  You can change you call to `capacity()` to `size()` to make sure you don't go past the end of the vector

```
for(int i = 0; i < partialSumList.size(); ++i)
```

The second thing I spot is that when `iterations % threadCount != 0` you have:

```
parameterList[threadCount].iterations = (iterations % threadCount) + (iterations / threadCount);
parameterList[threadCount].offset = threadCount - 1;
pthread_create(&threadList[threadCount], NULL, pi_calc, &parameterList[threadCount]);
```

Which is writing past the end of the vector.  Then when you join all of the threads you don't join the last thread as you do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < threadCount-1; ++i){
                              ^^^ uh oh.  we missed the last thread 
    pthread_join(threadList[i], &status);
    cout << status << endl;
}
```

Comment: I used `capacity` because I used `reserve` when I should have used `resize` and `size()` would return zero.  I made those changes and also changed `capacity` to `size`, still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @Lighthat  Please change your original post to indicate these adjustments.  The code you posted, threaded or non-threaded would not work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just did.

Comment: Regarding your edit, when I make `threadCount-1` just `threadCount`, I get a segmentation fault when it tries to join the last thread.

Comment: @Lighthat Is that after you fixed the part about setting one past the end of the vector instead of the last element of the vector?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that. It still looks like I should join up to `threadCount` since I'm using `<` and not `<=` but I guess not.

Comment: @Lighthat Did you also fix `pthread_create(&threadList[threadCount], NULL, pi_calc, &parameterList[threadCount])` to be `pthread_create(&threadList[threadCount - 1], NULL, pi_calc, &parameterList[threadCount - 1])`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I actually just increased the size of the vector by 1 so I didn't have to do that. Probably not the most efficient solution.